# Showing categories and their respective subcategories in a specific html structure

Tags: php, mysql, menu, show, categories

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="">Category 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Subcategory 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Subcategory 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Subcategory 3</a></li>
            <!-- Etc... -->
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="">Category 2</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Subcategory 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Subcategory 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Subcategory 3</a></li>
            <!-- Etc... -->

        </ul>
    </li>
    <!-- Etc... -->
</ul>
```

I am trying to show in a HTML document this structure generated by PHP. So what I want to show is the categories and their respective subcategories, retrieving the categories and subcategories from a MySQL DB. I know there are a lot of APIs to do it. But I want to know how to it by myself.

The DB in detail:

- Categories:

  -CID (PK)

  -Description
- Subcategories:

  -SID(PK)

  -Description

  -CID (FK)

Comment: `But I want to know how to it by myself.`.  Have you started something?

Comment: Show the data from the mysql table

Comment: Yes, I created the databases. And I can get by 'harcoded' selects the categories and subcategories, but obviously the idea is to do it dinamically.